# Heroku Login windows 10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

After installing heroku toolbelt

```
$ heroku version
heroku/toolbelt/3.42.33 (i386-mingw32) ruby/2.1.7
heroku-cli/4.27.18-9b2b68a (386-windows) go1.5.3
=== Installed Plugins
heroku-apps@1.2.3
heroku-cli-addons@0.2.0
heroku-fork@4.1.1
heroku-git@2.4.5
heroku-local@4.1.6
heroku-run@2.9.2
heroku-spaces@2.0.13
heroku-status@2.1.0
```

Then I try to login and I get following problem

```
$ heroku login
Enter your Heroku credentials.
Email: foo@bar.com
Password (typing will be hidden):
 !    Descripteur non valide
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: My advise is to contact Heroku [command line support](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-command). They have excellent customer service and are quick to respond

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is related to this known issue, https://github.com/heroku/heroku-cli/issues/84 . If you use command prompt to login and then switch back to mingw32 then you should be able to proceed as expected. The reason you did not receive the error that the issue references is due to internationalization, so our code did not trap this error properly. Please let me know if this does not work for you.

Comment: Hello thanks for your answer! I have since moved to ubuntu, and no more issues with rails. Meanwhile they can keep pretending that rails is actually cross platform compatible!